# Clearing R Workspace at Startup? Nothing works

Tags: r, rstudio

When I open R Studio, a previous workspace keeps loading. I have deleted .RData files, updated R, uninstalled and re-installed RStudio, and RStudio still loads the old workspace. RStudio also will not run any R code now, even after uninstalling and re-installing.

Is there a way to do a 'hard reset' of RStudio from the terminal?

UPDATE: I was able to delete hidden .R files through the terminal, but now commands will not run in RStudio.

Comment: R/RStudio will try to load `.Rdata` from the `HOME` directory and/or the current project directory. Are you in a project? Have you looked where `getwd()` says R is starting?

Comment: Thank you! I am not in a project. I can do this in R, but not in Rstudio. When I enter "getwd() in Rstudio, nothing happens. I also tried Tools -> Global Options, and nothing opens.

Comment: `getwd()` in RStudio does nothing? Type it in the console, not in the script pane ... if it still does nothing, then ... I have no idea, that suggests R is not running. (Caveat: I don't use the RStudio IDE; I have it installed but do not use it.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, nothing happens in RStudio. I can run everything just fine in the R Console though.

Comment: Got to Tools > GLobal options   and tell it to stop saving and stop loading.

Comment: Thanks Elin. I tried that, and nothing happens when I click on Global Options.